# Unzip files from S3 before putting them into Snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

I have data available in an S3 bucket we don't own, with a zipped folder containing files for each date.

We are using Snowflake as our data warehouse. Snowflake accepts gzip'd files, but does not ingest zip'd folders.

Is there a way to directly ingest the files into Snowflake that will be more efficient than copying them all into our own S3 bucket and unzipping them there, then pointing e.g. Snowpipe to that bucket? The data is on the order of 10GB per day, so copying is very doable, but would introduce (potentially) unnecessary latency and cost. We also don't have access to their IAM policies, so can't do something like S3 Sync.

I would be happy to write something myself, or use a product/platform like Meltano or Airbyte, but I can't find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using SnowSQL to load the data into Snowflake, and using Snowflake stage table/user/named stage to hold files at stages.

> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case. I use an **event based trigger** that runs a **Lambda function** everytime there is a new zipped file in my S3 folder. The Lambda functions opens the zipped files, gzips each individual file and re-uploads them to a different S3 folder. Here's the full working code: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9